# Parallel process a function which takes the previous function output as an argument

Tags: python-3.x, parallel-processing

I am trying to code the equation `H_n = Sum(Amp * B1 * B_{n-1})` in a parallel process over array `W`.

```
For i=0 Bn = Bn ** w, else Bn = B_{n-1} * B1 .
```

This is then multiplied by Amp and summed producing a `H` for each `w` in `W`.

How would I apply parallel processing to speed this up? I cannot figure out how parallel processing would know what the previous index Bn was if it has not been calculated yet, when the parallel processing splits W up into chunks to apply the function to.

For the `Bn` of a new chunk of `W` which each core is working on, the first `Bn` value for that chunk can be calculated by:

```
Bn[i] = Bn[0] * (B1**(i-1))
```

E.g if `W` is split into 8 arrays for 8 CPU cores, the first `Bn` value of each of the 8 arrays can be calculated with the above equation. It is then much quicker to calculate `H_w` by doing `sum(B_{i-1} * B1)`.

FYI this comes from:

```
exp(-j * w[ i ]  * t ) = exp(-j * delta_w * t) * exp(-j * w[i-1])
```

B is length 48474705

```
K=2**16
k=np.arange(1,K)
Fs=40e3
delta_w=2*np.pi*Fs/K
W=k*delta_w
Amp=[Amplitude(l,m,n,u) for u in U for l in L for m in M for n in N 
if dist(l,m,n,u) < 1500]
B=[np.exp(-1j*dist(l,m,n,u)/room.speed_of_sound) for u in U for l 
in L for m in M for n in N if dist(l,m,n,u) < 1500]
B1=[np.exp(-1j*delta_w*dist(l,m,n,u)/room.speed_of_sound) for u in 
U for l in L for m in M for n in N if dist(l,m,n,u) < 1500]
Bn=np.array(B)


i=0
for w in W:
    if i=0:
        Bn=Bn**w
        Hw[i]=np.einsum('i,i->',Amp,Bn)
        i=i+1
    else:
        Bn=np.array(Bn*B1)
        Hw[i]=np.einsum('i,i->',Amp,Bn)        
        i=i+1
return(Hw)
```

Comment: I would split W into three arrays, use the equation to calculate the first Bn for each of the three arrays and then run the for loop on each of the three arrays at the same time. These three arrays are then appended to each other. However I do not know how to do this with parallel processing.

Comment: Thank you for editing the question. Perhaps I should rephrase the question as, how to I split W into n arrays for n cores to process the for loop on at the same time?